# Maven archetype for glassfish runtime

Tags: eclipse, maven, glassfish, archetypes

How can I create j2ee project with maven having glassfish 4 as target runtime?

I use eclipse Mars. I follow the 'Dynamic web project' wizard, I select glassfish 4 as 'Target runtime'. When wizard ends I open the project and under the nodes 'Java resources->Libraries' I can see the glassfish system library bundle.

Now I would create the same project using maven. I've searched for an archetype giving me the same library bundle to avoid problem on deploy but I haven't found a definitive one. 
The more close appears to be the jersey-quickstart-webapp but when I look the dependencies these are just a bunch respect to glassfish runtime. It's possible? It sounds strange to me, maybe I am making mistakes, am I following the right approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with was this:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=mygroup -DartifactId=myapp -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
        -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=webapp-javaee7
```

Where `mygroup` and `myapp` are yours to determine.

Then, in the generated pom.xml, add this property (in the properties element):

```
<glassfish.version>4.1.1</glassfish.version>
```

Set the final name in the build element (we're going to refer to it shortly):

```
<finalName>myapp</finalName>
```

Then add this plugin to configure the Glassfish embedded runtime, in the plugins element:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.embedded</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <autoDelete>true</autoDelete>
        <ports>
            <http-listener>8080</http-listener>
            <https-listener>8181</https-listener>
        </ports>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>deploy</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>none</phase>
            <configuration>
                <app>target/${project.build.finalName}.war</app>
                <contextRoot>/${project.build.finalName}</contextRoot>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>admin</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>admin</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
            <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I then use `mvn clean install embedded-glassfish:run` to run the server with a freshly built application.

Hope you like it.

Comment: I've discarded the archetype from codehaus because codehaus has terminated all services. However your code is a good starting point. I will study it and grow my Maven knowledge. Thank you.